# Use of “where” in a question when referring to something other than a place

Tags: questions

I am teaching English online and we have this activity in which we ask a student to formulate questions from a sentence. The sentence is

> There was an error in the client's invoice.

So the question is expected to be

> Where was there an error?

The answer should be

> There was an error **in the client's invoice**.

What would be a simple yet clear explanation why *where* is the appropriate question and not *what*?

<sub>Note: this is my first time asking here so I'd appreciate refinements in the way I'm asking.</sub>

Comment: Any explanation like that would be totally wrong. Both *"Where was there an error"* and *"What was there an error **in**?"* are perfectly good questions for that answer.

Comment: There are many questions which could elicit the (complete and formal) (and correct) answer 'There was an error in the client's invoice.' For instance, 'Why did you take so long sorting out the paperwork?' / 'Why was the boss so angry?' This sort of question is very open-ended. 'Where did the error occur?' presupposes knowledge that there was an error _somewhere_. 'What was there in the client's invoice?' sounds silly, but 'What was it about the client's invoice that caused such a problem?' would generate the wanted answer. Or 'Bob lost it' / 'It was written in Gujerati' .... >> Poor question!

Comment: Exactly. Poor question. If you want to get a specific response, you have to make it the only possible response. There's only one question that can be formed from _There was an error in the client's invoice_, and that's _Was there was an error in the client's invoice?_. To ask a wh-question, you need more information about the context and the speaker's state of information.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The expected answer to the question 'Where was there an error?' is 'in the client's invoice'. Also, We try to stick to the words used in a given sentence.  You see we do this activity to simply teach students grammar without having to discuss further into grammar rules or grammar terms. That's why I am trying to figure out how to explain this the simplest way that students will understand. Of course there are cases that we need to talk about grammar rules especially when a student brings it up.

Comment: The title of your question doesn't seem to relate to the body of the question. The title asks about the use of _where_ when referring to something other than a place, but the body asks about “in the client’s invoice”, which **is** a place… so what exactly is the question?

Comment: Hi Janus. Sorry what I meant with 'place' is kinda literal. I meant location..such as in your house, in the garage, a country, a city. You see our students are low beginners they tend to interpret some english terms literally. So when we say 'where' they think it always refers to a location.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP might get a better answer for her purpose at ELL http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The comment by @ab2 is right. ELL is a great place for questions about teaching English as well as questions from English language learners.

Answer (score 0):

**Where** is appropriate because invoices have internal locations. The top of the invoice is a header, possibly with some invoice information presented in boxes

This is followed by one or more lines which have a standard format defined by columns

The bottom of the invoice is a footer containing summary information including the total amount and the tax charged (most of this information being displayed in boxes).

A single error in an invoice is located either in one of the header or footer boxes or in a specific column in a specific line. An answer to the question could be **In the quantity column of item 4**. It wouldn't tell you what the error was but would tell you where to look and, if you understood the process, would also tell you which other locations on the invoice were affected (in this case the charge for line 4, the total amount invoiced and the tax). It is also true that **the quantity column of line 4** is a different place on the invoice from **the item cost for line 2**.

The point is that **the quantity column of item 4** is a location on the invoice in the same way that **square E7** is a location on a map so asking **where is the error?** is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: The OP says that the expected answer to the *where* question is "There was an error in the client's invoice." So the "where" question would need to reference "the client's invoice" (not the components of the invoice) as one of the locations. Other 'locations' to be considered before rejection include "the supplier's invoice" and "their own invoice".

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation BoldBen. Really appreciate it. However Lawrence is right that the expected answer to the question is 'in the client's invoice.' You see we do this activity to simply teach students grammar without having to discuss further into grammar rules or grammar terms. That's why I am trying to figure out how to explain this the simplest way that students will understand. Of course there are cases that we need to talk about grammar rules especially when a student brings it up.